# Event 4656 on file server for files and folders not opened

Tags: windows, windows-event-log, file-server

Can someone explain why on the audit events of a file server there's plenty of 4656 events even if the file or folders have not directly been opened?
For example, if you open the root directory H: , in the events there are lots 4656 related to the folders inside it. If you open the folder H:\examplefolder\ , you will have lots of 4656 for files and folders in it, without touching them.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

If you enabled auditing for everything there will be a lot of noise.  If list folder is enabled or read attributes for the files then you may want to refine your auditing criteria.

[image: Noisy auditing]